# Curious about the function of ~in the following code

Tags: python

```
pd_selftest = pd_selftest[pd_selftest['SICCD'] != 0]

pd_selftest = pd_selftest[~pd_selftest['SICCD'].isnull()]
```

I'd like to know what the function of the `~` is in the above code.

Comment: `~[True,False,True]` == `[False,True,False]`

Answer (score 1):

That's the bit-wise `invert` or `not` operator.  So, it returns only those lines where the `SICCID` column is not null.  I would probably use the word `not` in this case.

Comment: `not` doesn't work for vectors of results, where `~` does; `not` probably wouldn't work in the OP's case.